# Tracking SSH access on a client MacOS machine

Tags: macos, logging

There are many sources describing how to track and detect SSH attempt on a server. What I am asking is the opposite. I have a MacOS (Ventura) and I would like to track where this machine has SSH-connected to, the kind of traffic it makes to those servers, etc. Which log file should I look at and what type of events are they.